# Jekyll keeps replacing file with default file

Tags: ruby, jekyll

This only happens 50% of the time, but sometimes when I change and save my `index.html` or `main.scss` file, all of my code is reverted to the original default Jekyll files.

When I `undo` the change I've made, I can see my old code.

To create my Jekyll files, here's all I've done ([from the Jekyll docs](http://jekyllrb.com/)):

```
 $ gem install jekyll
 $ jekyll new my-awesome-site
 $ cd my-awesome-site
 ~/my-awesome-site $ jekyll serve
```

After this happens, my terminal looks like this:

```
Auto-regeneration: enabled for '/Users/myname/dev/foldername'
Configuration file: /Users/myname/dev/foldername/_config.yml
Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000/
Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
[2016-05-31 17:27:44] ERROR `/css/style.css' not found.
[2016-05-31 17:27:44] ERROR `/js/main.js' not found.
Regenerating: 1 file(s) changed at 2016-05-31 17:27:59 ...done in 0.128183 seconds.
```

I'm new to using Jekyll, but I'm assuming that this is happening because I have *Auto-regeneration* enabled, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Maybe you can [fill a Jekyll issue](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/new).

Comment: Hmm, thanks for checking! I'll do that.

Comment: By any chance are you editing files in the ``/_site/`` folder? This folder gets overwritten when Jekyll detects changes and re-builds your site.